Regarding the repercussions of git hard reset on remote
Resetting remote to a certain commit
We would like to reset the remote to a certain commit on a specific branch (say branch A) in our project. However there are the following concerns:

We recently did a merge onto the branch A from origin, in order to make it current (this merge is the latest in the commit history of the branch)
Another branch B has been created from branch A after the merge, and all the changes have been pushed to the remote; the idea is that we would have all the original commits from A on B, even if we were to hard reset A to a previous commit

Is this understanding correct? Would we still have all the original commits on A still available on B even after we do a hard reset on A to a previous commit? This question stems from the fact that B has been branched off of A to begin with.

In Git, branches are implemented as files containing the SHA1 of their head commit. Moving a branch around to make it point different commits does not alter the commit history (the directed acyclic graph). The commit graph will always be the same regardless of how many times a branch is repositioned to a different commit.
Quoting the paragraph Branches in a Nutshell from Git Pro:

A branch in Git is simply a lightweight movable pointer to one of these commits.

You can check this yourself, and inspect the content of any of your branches by opening with a text editor one of the files under refs\heads. The editor will show you the SHA1 of the commit pointed by the branch (its head commit).
In your case, after merging the remote's changes into your local branch A and creating B from it, you would have the following situation:
a -- b -- c -- d -- f
                    |
                 (branchA,
                  branchB)

After the reset, the commit graph would still be the same, where each commit still points to the same parents. What we've done is just making the branch point to a different commit.
a -- b -- c -- d -- f
          |         |
      (branchA)  (branchB)

So, to answer your question

Would we still have all the original commits on A still available on B even after we do a hard reset on A to a previous commit?

Yes, you would still have on B the original commits on A, even after hard resetting A on a previous commit.

Your understanding is correct: changes to A won't automatically affect B. It's still possible for someone to update B to reflect A's new state (using rebase or merge or a UI tool), but that will have to be done manually.

So even if B were to be created off of A,  it shouldn't impact B if we were to walk A back a few commits?

Walk it back, walk it forward, do both, whichever. B won't change until somebody changes it.
